# Parse a MySQL insert statement with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a huge MySQL Dump with lots of insert statement using the multiple rows syntax. I need to search for specific content in each row, therefore I want to split the statement to have each row in a extra string.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c)
VALUES (1,2,'test1'),
       (4,5,'test2 (test2a),
       (test2b)'),(7,8,'test3');
```

Result should be a list of the 3 blocks

```
[
    "1,2,'test1'",
    "4,5,'test2 (test2a),(test2b)'",
    "7,8,'test3'"
]
```

Question, what is the most efficient way to achieve this. Is it regular expression with some magic? Language does not matter for me. Can do with Java, PHP, Perl ...

Comment: Are the column numbers fixed throughout the dump? Or should you be considering a possibility of multiple rows? Also, did you consider loading this into a mysql database and querying for the values? That seems more straight forward compared to parsing a free format text file using Regular expressions.

Comment: Why do you want/need to do this?  You could use a `UNION` query but perhaps this would be better handled in your app layer.

Comment: the dump is very large and I need this to verify history data within multiple dumps. lets say I have 10 dumps each > 3GB or so (with gz) and I want to search for keywords in each of the dumps to see history of a few rows (with the key words).
the column numbers are fix yes

someone deleted rows and I need to verify when that happend. so i want to search the dumps on what date the row was still present

Comment: `regex` will be a bad choice for this because of `nesting` structure..
See here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets

Comment: Please tell us more details around your problem. Maybe you are on the wrong track.

Comment: as described I have a dump of the database every day. but the dump is very large > 3GB (with gz) to load each dump search for the row and dump the database again would be a very disk / mysql intensive process. i just want to search through each dump for a certain row to tell a customer by when it was deleted (no longer present)

Comment: I question whether any of the regexps (in the 'dup' question) will work _in mysql_.